# Windows service with RegisterDeviceNotification

Tags: c#, winapi, service

I wanted to listen to device notifications in a windows service in C#. I use RegisterDeviceNotification with RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx. It's a standard code from the Internet, but it doesn't work.

What can be the problem?

The code sample:

```
        try
        {
            _handler = new ServiceControlHandlerEx(ServiceControlHandler);

            IntPtr handle2 = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(this.serviceName, _handler, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (handle2 == IntPtr.Zero)
                return false;

            DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE deviceInterface = new DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE();
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(deviceInterface);
            deviceInterface.dbcc_size = size;
            deviceInterface.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
            IntPtr bufferDeviceInterface = default(IntPtr);
            bufferDeviceInterface = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(deviceInterface, bufferDeviceInterface, true);

            _deviceHandle = RegisterDeviceNotification(handle2, bufferDeviceInterface,
                DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE | DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES);

            if (_deviceHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                return false;

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be seen in the posted code sample, but RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx and  RegisterDeviceNotification must not be invoked in a separate thread. These methods must be invoked in a "main thread", i.e. method overriding ServiceBase.OnStart().